# Mongoskin: set a document schema

Tags: node.js, mongoskin

I want to use node & mongoskin, and define a document's schema ( which key is unique, which key has a default value, etc... )

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

well...you can't
if you like to use those features use "mongoose"